# Python 1Hz measurement temperature

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I want to create csv file in python ,storing data from the sensor plus time stamp of the reading .But sensor measures fast and I need exactly 1 measurment from the sensor exactly after 1 sec.For example sensor value is 20 at time 12:34:15.and i need  value exactly at  12:34:16 .I do not have to use time.sleep because it creates delay more than second and will affect the log file if i have to take readings more than hundred.

Comment: I guess it all depends on how you interact with your sensor (which you told us nothing about).

Answer (score 0):

Consumer PCs do not have real-time operating systems and there is no guarantee that a particular process will execute at least once per second and certainly no guarantee that it will be executing at each 1 second interval.  If you want precision timed measurements with Python, you should look as [Micropython](https://micropython.org/) executing on a microcontroller board.  It may be able to do what you want.  Python on a Raspberry Pi board might also work better than a PC.

On a regular PC, I would start with something using [perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter).

```
from time import perf_counter as timer
from somewhere import sensor, save  # read temperature, save value
t0 = t1 = timer()
delta = .99999  # adjust by experiment to average 1 sec reading intervals
while True:
    while t1 - t0 < delta:
        t1 = timer()
    value = sensor())
    save(value)
    t0 = t1
```